# Programming R functions that accommodate spelling variations

Tags: r, function

Suppose you want to program an `R` function that uses an argument with different possible spellings (e.g., using the arguments `centre` and `center` from British and US English respectively).  You want the function to allow the user to use either spelling, but treated essentially as a single argument.  What is "best practice" for how to structure a function like this?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I cannot speak to best practice, I am going to give one possible structure for this task, which seems to me to accommodate spelling variations.  This is the method that is used in some of the base `R` functions for probability distributions when there are alternative parameterisations of the distribution (e.g., in the gamma distribution you can specify a scale or rate parameter).  In these cases the function includes both arguments and then uses a clever set of commands to ensure that the function will use whichever argument is specified by the user.

To create a function using `centre` and `centre` as spelling variations for the same argument, you could use the structure shown below.  Note that the computation in this method is done using the *second* spelling variation, and this latter argument is set equal to the former argument in the default values for the function.  This ensures that the function will use the user-specified argument.

```
MY_FUNCTION <- function(centre = 0, center = centre, ...) {
  
  #Check inputs
  if (!missing(centre) && !missing(center)) {
  if (sum((centre - center)^2) < 1e-15) { 
    warning("specify 'centre' or 'center' but not both") } else {
    stop("Error: specify 'centre' or 'center' but not both") } }
  
  Do some computations using the 'center' argument and then give output }
```

Here is an example of this function structure applied to generate a function `DISTANCE` that computes the Euclidean distance between a point and a centre/centre.

```
DISTANCE <- function(point, centre = 0, center = centre, ...) {
  
  #Check inputs
  if (!missing(centre) && !missing(center)) {
  if (sum((centre - center)^2) < 1e-15) { 
    warning("specify 'centre' or 'center' but not both") } else {
    stop("Error: specify 'centre' or 'center' but not both") } }
  
  sqrt(sum((point - center)^2)) }
```

In the examples below, we demonstrate that this structure works properly regardless of whether the user uses the `centre` argument or the `center` argument.  In the pathological case where the user specifies both arguments (which they really shouldn't) the function compares the values `center` and `centre`; if the values are close together then the function continues but gives the user a warning not to specify both arguments; if the values are not close together then the function stops and gives an error message telling the user not to specify both arguments.

```
POINT <- c(4, 2, 3);
CENT  <- c(0, 3, 1);

DISTANCE(point = POINT, centre = CENT);
[1] 4.582576

DISTANCE(point = POINT, center = CENT);
[1] 4.582576

DISTANCE(point = POINT, centre = CENT, center = CENT);
[1] 4.582576
Warning message:
In DISTANCE(point = POINT, centre = CENT, center = CENT) :
  specify 'centre' or 'center' but not both

DISTANCE(point = POINT, centre = CENT, center = CENT + 1);
Error in DISTANCE(point = POINT, centre = CENT, centre = CENT + 1) : 
  Error: specify 'centre' or 'center' but not both
```